# Confirm Before Form Submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I created a PHP page to delete from my database. This PHP page is the action of a form submission. The form is submitted by clicking a pic of "X" sign. 
How can I ask user to confirm before the submission of the form and therfore deleting from my database?

This is my code:

```
<form method='POST' action='delete.php'><input type='image' src='images/delete.png' class='del' alt='Submit Form' />
```

I tried to do it inline by adding this to my form tag, but it did not work:

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');"
```

Comment: use `onclick` for the button and not `onsubmit` for the form.

Comment: If you want to be sure that the confirmation is asked, you need to do a confirmation page called on submit on server side (a new php file with a two buttons form and the previously entered informations that calls delete.php when "yes" is choosen). Once you have done that, you can add a javascript layer with ajax calls to improve the user experience. The advantage of this approach is that your app can work with and without javascript.

Comment: Just loving on how much attention I'm getting *lol*

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sesekeruqa/1/edit?html,output — That works fine when I test it.

Comment: You obviously are leaving out some important code and as to how exactly that is being used. I hope you're not only responding to "answers" only; we need some feedback up here too.

Comment: I am trying your suggestions one by one. :)

Comment: @SaharAlsadah you tagged as "php" but no code to support your question. I'm betting that you're echoing that somewhere and using the wrong quotes or not escaping the single quotes. Everyone's answers were downvoted because of what you're not showing us. Not my downvotes btw. Edit: Which many have deleted their answers.

Comment: what am I not showing exactly? all the related code is up here in my question post. What are you referring to ?

Comment: @SaharAlsadah my comment was clear, what else do you want me to write? I am moving on now. Good luck with this. I wasted enough time already as you did for everyone else including "yours".

Comment: sorry it is anything but clear to me :). Thanks anyway

Comment: @SaharAlsadah — If all the related code is in the post, why is it that I can't reproduce the problem in my test case? http://jsbin.com/sesekeruqa/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I am writing the html tags within the php tag, so I'm using echo before; ex: echo "<form method='POST' action='delete.php'><input type='image' src='images/delete.png' class='del' alt='Submit Form'  onclick='return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to submit this form?\');' />" . I tried it with both onclick and onsubmit, both didn't work. may be the single quotes are not being interpreted properly. I tried to run this with and without the back slash before single quote, same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a comment by the OP:

> ```
> echo "onclick='return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to submit this form?\');'"
> ```

You can't use single quotes in an attribute value delimited with single quotes.

Your options are:

**Use double quotes in the JS**

```
echo "onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to submit this form?\");'"
```

**Use double quotes in the HTML**

```
echo "onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');\""
```

**Use entities**

```
echo "onclick='return confirm(&quot;Are you sure you want to submit this form?&quot;);\""
```

When out you put JavaScript inside an HTML attribute value inside a PHP string you have three different languages all mixed together, and you have to be very, very careful with your escaping so that you escape the right characters for the right languages at the right times.

As a rule of thumb, it is better to keep that contents of PHP strings to a minimum. Only drop into PHP mode when you have a variable.

```
?>
    <form method='POST' action='delete.php'>
        <input type='image' src='images/delete.png' class='del' alt='Submit Form' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');" />
    </form>
<?php
```

For the same reason, it is better to keep your JavaScript in an external file and attach event handlers with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `onFOO` attributes.

Comment: I separated the php code from the the HTML tags and it worked. Thank you so much for your detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
  <form method='POST' action='delete.php' onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');">
<input type='image' src='images/delete.png' class='del' alt='Submit Form' /></form>
```

Comment: That's what the OP said they were doing.

Comment: If it works for you, but doesn't work for the OP, then telling them to do whatever they are doing already doesn't solve their problem, does it?

Comment: i think you forgot to put </form> or something, copy the above code and check it works for you or not

Comment: Omitting the end tag makes no difference to http://jsbin.com/faloboveyo/1/edit?html,output working

Comment: I don't know why it did not seem to work. thank you anyway for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution if you use jQuery on your site.

## Method jQuery

Your HTML:

```
<form class="sendingForm" method='POST' action='delete.php'> 
    <input type='image' src='images/delete.png' class='del' alt='Submit Form' />
</form>
```

So I give a class: *sendingForm*

Your JavaScript section:

```
$(".sendingForm").submit(function() {
    if (confirm("Please confirm!")) return true;
    else return false;       
});
```

You can check it: http://jsfiddle.net/d6gem0ty/

## Method inline

The shortest solution is maybe easier. Here have only HTML and a onclick event.

```
<form class="sendingForm" method='POST' action='delete.php'>
<input onclick="return confirm('Please confirm!')"  type='image' src='images/delete.png' class='del' alt='Submit Form' />
```

You can check it: http://jsfiddle.net/d6gem0ty/1/